# Why useSelector returns new object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i don't understand why useSelector returns new object instead old from store.

i have:

```js
const date = useSelector(state => state.dashboard);
```

`date` each time a new object, why ?
i take object from state, not new object.

`state.dashboard` doesn't change, other parts of the store change.
All reducers are clean function, don't mutable state.

in the redux devtool i can see that `state.dashboard` does not change.

DashboardState has interface:

```js
interface DashboardState {
  from: Moment; // it's same Date
  to: Moment; // it's same Date
}
```

Why my selector return new object?
if i add shallowEqual `useSelector((state) => state.dashboard, shallowEqual)`, then it's okay.

UPD.

```js
const initialState: DashboardState = {
  from: moment().add(-7, 'd'),
  to: moment(),
};
```

store:
[image: redux store dashboard]

Redux devtool raw store:

```js
{
// .. other parts of the store
dashboard: {
  from: '2020-12-17T19:03:16.113Z',
  to: '2020-12-24T19:03:16.115Z'
}
// .. other parts
```

For any change in the store (even except for dashboards), the selector returns a new object

Comment: Can you show us the store and the initial state value so we can see what is happening?

Comment: @Shayan, yes, i've updated question

Answer (score 0):

MomentJS is [mutable and deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), use dayJS.

Comment: But i don't mutable my moment objec

Comment: it happens even with strings